# GraphQL - using fragments with interfaces

Tags: graphql, union-types

I have following union that is described on the server.

```js
type BaseActivity {
 id: Int!
}

type PostActivity implements BaseActivity {
 content: String!
}

type ConcludeActivity implements BaseActivity {
 field: String!
}

type Activity = PostActivity | ConcludeActivity
```

I try to query on this object, but using fragments.

```js
fragment PostActivityFragment on PostActivity {
 content: string
}

fragment ConcludeActivityFragment on ConcludeActivity {
 content: string
}

query Activities {
 id
 ...PostActivityFragment
 ...ConcludeActivityFragment
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I'm getting `content` and `field` :(
The only solution that works is:

```js
query Activities {
 id
 ... on PostActivity {
  content
 }
 ... on ConcludeActivity {
  field
 }
}
```

But, because of that, I'm losing the benefits of fragments and types..
Any ideas, how to achieve queries on union using fragments?

Comment: What's the actual output you're getting from the first query?  The fragment syntax doesn't look right as you've shown it: there aren't types in fragment definitions, so the colon instead introduces [field alias](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Field-Alias) syntax (querying a field named `string`, but naming it `content` in the output); I wouldn't expect this query to validate against the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
query Activities {
  id
  ... on PostActivity {
    ...PostActivityFragment
  }
  ... on ConcludeActivity {
    ...ConcludeActivityFragment
  }
}
```

because
This way, you're specifying the usage of fragments for each specific type within the union Activity. The ... on TypeName syntax is an inline fragment, and it allows you to specify which fragment should be applied to each concrete type within the union.

Your original attempt with ...PostActivityFragment and ...ConcludeActivityFragment outside of any type didn't work because GraphQL doesn't automatically know which fragment to apply to each type in the union.

Comment: Hmm.. it seems that my solution works, however the problem is that I'm using graphql-codegen and it doesn't generate types correctly :/